# How to assign cpu affinity for Python 3 subprocess?

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, cpu, affinity

I am very much a novice at Python.

I am running a Tkinter GUI on Windows 7 and Windows 10.  I have a subprocess running a data logger routine at 1 KHz.  I would like to set a cpu affinity for the subprocess,

I am building with Python 3.8.

Comment: Are you looking for something [like this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sched_setaffinity)

Comment: I need to find the process id for the datalogger subprocess then I think it will work Thanks.

Comment: I have used sched_setaffinity from the sched.h library in Linux but am not sure how it will work in Python.  I will let you know.

Comment: It appears that the os.sched_setaffinity(pid, mask) function is available on Unix/Linux only.

Comment: This seems a bit more complicated than I thought. I guess you need to go with pywin32 to get the [CurrentProcess](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32process__GetCurrentProcess_meth.html) and I guess you are looking for [SetProcessPriorityBoost](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32process__SetProcessPriorityBoost_meth.html) which will have this [behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setprocesspriorityboost). Take a look at [win32process](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32process.html)

Comment: [Get](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32process__GetProcessAffinityMask_meth.html) and [SetPriorityMask](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32process__SetProcessAffinityMask_meth.html) are also available, to have your [process in specific kernel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setprocesspriorityboost)

Comment: Thanks.  I will check that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `psutil` library. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74533316/7514021) answer should help you.