# Tasket cmd in Python (windows)

Tags: python

Hi all I am just wondering how I can use Taskset command in windows?

Here's Part of code which is written in python and I am running it on windows it is giving error as `taskset' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

here's code below :-

````
    event_list = df.to_records(index=False)
    event_list  = list(event_list)
    os.system("taskset -p 0xff %d" % os.getpid())
    p = Pool(processes=60)
    p.starmap(calc_hazard,event_list)

print(time.time()-t_initial)```
````

Comment: This should help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829974/taskset-equivalent-in-windows

Comment: actually i tried it but i am not able to understand how to run it, can you please explain me ? thank you so much

Comment: I didn't understood it neither, I just found it and it seems to be an answer to your problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [taskset equivalent in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829974/taskset-equivalent-in-windows)

Comment: No buddy :(   lets see i am trying to find out

Comment: If you have powershell, [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1083845/what-is-equivalent-of-taskset-on-powershell) can help you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) library which implements the taskset command. For example:

```
p = psutil.Process(pid)
p.cpu_affinity(cpus)
```

where `cpus` is a list of integers specifying the new CPUs affinity. The documentation is [here](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=affinity#psutil.Process.cpu_affinity).